# What are the libraries to add header in api manager wso2

Tags: java, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

Could you please tell me what are the exact libraries that are needed to add mediator (java method)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
        <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[Follow this.](http://blog.lasindu.com/2014/05/creating-simple-class-mediator.html)

You also can use WSO2 Develeoper Studio [to create a class mediator](http://achala11.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-write-custom-mediator-wso2-esb.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I used the version wso2 aim v2.0.0 what's the exactly version should include in the project I looked for the version that included in lib of wso2 that is 2.1.7 which not find in maven repository

Comment: Updated the answer.